# How to perform keyboard combinations in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, keyboard, combinations, shortcut

I would like to create a script that will perform keyboard combinations in Javascript.

For example : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to close the current window.

How to do that ?

Comment: http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you can write:

```
$(document).keydown(function(event) {
    var keyChar = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    if (keyChar == "w" && event.ctrlKey) {
        // CTRL+W pressed
    }
});
```

or just use this simple plugin [hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys)

Answer (score 0):

Use [shortcut.js](https://github.com/blainekasten/shortcut.js). You can use it like so:

```
function closeWindow(e){ /* Code to close window */ }
shortcut('ctrl w').bindsTo(closeWindow);
```